# error while installing streamsets data collector in emr. Getting the following error

Tags: shell, hadoop, sh, emr, streamsets

facing the below issue while installing streamsets in emr after starting sdc we are giving the below command

```
ssh -N -p 22 hadoop@ec2-34-207-150-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com -i /home/hadoop/sterling-emr-keypair.pem -L 18630:localhost:18630
```

the error given is:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 18630
Could not request local forwarding.
^CKilled by signal 2.
```

because of this error i am unable to access stremsets UI on localhost

Comment: try to change the port 18630 to another one. It seems it's being used.

Comment: streamsets data collector uses only 18630 port.,,And no other process is using the port 18630

Comment: What about on the local machine - is something listening on 18630 there?